# Auto hide bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want to hide automatically the Boostrap tooltip after few seconds.

```
 <input type="text" title="" data-placement="bottom" style="width:200px" data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control Waring" name="medicine_name" id="medicine_name" data-original-title="Please Enter Valid medicine name">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has this out of the box, you can set a delay property in options (in js)

```
delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
```

and in HTML:

```
data-delay='{"show":"500", "hide":"100"}'
```

where hide will get triggered after 100 ms

Comment: No, `hide` is the delay before the tooltip is hidden when the mouse pointer leaves the target. As long as the pointer is on the target the tooltip will be shown. I believe the OP wanted to know how to make the tooltip go away after a period of time when the pointer is still over the target.

Comment: @Paul not necessarily - I also had this same question, due to use of a tooltip on a button that, when pressed, adds lots of HTML to an existing DOM, and moves the button away as a result. Without the auto-hide, the user has to scroll up the page and click the tooltip to remove it.

Answer (score 25):

I use this for page-wide auto-hide on all bootstrap tooltips:

```
$(function () {
   $(document).on('shown.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(e.target).tooltip('hide');
      }, 10000);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$('#element').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
    $('#element').tooltip('destroy');
   }, 2000);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13k7nv4q/)

No idea why even bootstrap 4 does not have this feature build in. Anyway

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="helloworld" data-trigger="click" type="button">click</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('show.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).data('trigger') == 'click') {
    var timeoutDataName = 'shownBsTooltipTimeout';
    if ($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName) != null) {
      clearTimeout($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName));
    }
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      $(e.target).click();
    }, 5000);
    $(e.target).data(timeoutDataName, timeout);
  }
});

$(document).on('hide.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).data('trigger') == 'click') {
    var timeoutDataName = 'shownBsTooltipTimeout';
    if ($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName) != null) {
      clearTimeout($(e.target).data(timeoutDataName));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Not sure why it doesn't come with it as parameter options, but this saved my day..Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bootstrap v4 then, you can try this:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.tooltip', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function() {   //calls click event after a certain time
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
}, 4000);
});
```

`show.bs.tooltip` event is called after a tooltip `show` is triggered.

Source: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#events

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple Answer

```
$(selector).tooltip({title:"Event", trigger:"focus or hover only", delay:{hide:800}});
```

Give only hide parameter in delay option.

I don't know why doesn't work on click event.....

but on focus(tab of click) and hover event works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and all else did not work the this is a straight forward solution on jquery.

HTML:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Button-tooltip" data-placement="top">
<button role="button">Button</button>
</span>
```

Jquery:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).tooltip("hide"); 
})
```

were the data selector is the element you want to target so each time your mouse leaves that element it will hide the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for bootstrap 3 manual onclick tooltip autohide:

```
var el = $(document).find('#element');
el.tooltip({
  "title": "Some title",
  "trigger": "manual",
  "placement": "top"
});
el.tooltip('show');
setTimeout(function() {
  el.tooltip('hide');
}, 900);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need not to write additional js code, cause this functionality already exists in Bootstrap. Let me suppose that you need not to hide after seconds, but you need to remove annoying tooltip if it already has been read. If you need behavior such as auto-hide Bootstrap tooltip (or popover) on focus out or click anywhere outside of tooltip, use and stylize element which can be in focus. For instance BUTTON.

In template use code:

```
<button class="tooltip-button"
        role="button"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        data-placement="right"
        data-html="true"
        data-trigger="focus hover"
        data-title="Your tooltip html code or text">*</button>
```

Style with SCSS to introduce button as regular text:

```
button.tooltip-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  &:not(:disabled) {
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

And don't forget in your base template initialize all tooltips on page:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple popups and could not get the popup id easily from the element it was being created from. 
This is the code I came up with, posting in case it will help someone else:

```
// get the id for the latest popover
var popid = document.getElementsByClassName('popover')[document.getElementsByClassName('popover').length -1].id;
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + popid).fadeOut('slow');
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger option as hover only. when the cursor is leaving the particular elements and automatically hide tooltip.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      animation: true
      , container: 'body'
      , html: true
      , placement: 'auto'
      , trigger: 'hover'
});
```